# Check for distinct value of a property in list except nulls

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have a class with few properties like this.

```
public class CheckList
{
    public int ACTION_ID { get; set; }
    public string ACTION_NAME { get; set; }
    public string ACTION_DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
    public bool? ACTIVE { get; set; }
}
```

and List of this class in my controller.

```
List<CheckList> validChecklists = _ChecklistRepo.GetAll();
var ifActionsAreSame = validChecklists .Select(t => t.ACTION_NAME).Distinct().Count();
if (ifActionsAreSame < validChecklists .Count)
{
    return Ok(new {ActionsAreDuplicated= true });
}
```

Sometimes the ACTION_NAME of multiple items Can be null in the list. This code treats the null value as duplicate. What changes I need to do to exclude null fields in the ACTION_NAME field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Then remove the `null`s with `Where`:

```
int notNullDistinctActionNames = validChecklists 
    .Where(t => t.ACTION_NAME != null)
    .Select(t => t.ACTION_NAME)
    .Distinct()
    .Count();
```

You could also use the `Count` overload:

```
int notNullDistinctActionNames = validChecklists 
    .Select(t => t.ACTION_NAME)
    .Distinct()
    .Count(s => s != null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a separate list first where all items with a null actions are removed. Then compare the count of that list to the distinct actions count on that list. But that would require 2 steps.

An alternative would be to use a `group by` on the original list and check if any group with a value (action not null) has more than one item:

```
bool AllActionsUnique = validChecklists.GroupBy(c=>c.ACTION_NAME).All(g=>g.Key==null || g.Count() == 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var ifActionsAreSame = validChecklists
    .Select(t => t.ACTION_NAME)
    .Distinct()
    .OfType<CheckList>()
    .Count();
```

> According to MSDN, Enumerable.OfType<(Of <(TResult>)>) Method and Queryable.OfType<(Of <(TResult>)>) Method, the “.OfType” method is used to filter the collections based on a specified type, and the “null” is not type specific, it can be any reference type and null-able type, so in this scenario, the “.OfType” will not work to filter the “null” values.

[MSDN Question reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/682cd77b-55e8-40b2-ad83-60b27cb1a22b/neat-trick-user-oftypewhatever-to-filter-out-nulls?forum=linqprojectgeneral)